# PHP's call_user_func_array in Swift

Tags: php, swift, reflection, functional-programming

Is there any equivalent function in Swift (Apple's language) similar to PHP's 
`call_user_func_array` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php), which allows calling a function with an array of parameters?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't call a function with an array of parameters in Swift because function arguments need to be available at compile-time.

What you can do is get the arguments from an array

```
let args = ["John", 18]

let name = args[0] as! String
let age = args[1] as! Int
```

And then call the function with `name` and `age`.

Note that this will crash if the args list is empty or if one of the args isn't a `String` or `Int`